# Navigating Challenges in 3D Preview Implementation: Issues with View Updates

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, procedural-generation, procedural

The issue I'm encountering pertains to the preview functionality in the 3D generation. My intention is to incorporate a central preview that can be manipulated freely, surrounded by three smaller canvases on the right. These smaller canvases are meant to display static views showcasing different perspectives of the generated content.

One challenge arises during the initial project launch: when I initiate it for the first time, two objects are created. Upon attempting to reposition them, one object intersects with the other. Subsequently regenerating the scene addresses the issue of the overlapping objects, but a new problem arises. The preview canvases, situated below the initial generation, fail to update accordingly. Instead, they persist in displaying the initial generation's views, failing to reflect the changes made in the subsequent regeneration.

I acknowledge that my explanation might not be entirely clear, so I strongly suggest running the project to observe the error firsthand.

```
// perlin.js  & pruebas.js

var perlin = new PerlinNoise(); // Agrega esta línea para crear una instancia de PerlinNoise
var scene, camera, renderer;
var llanuraGroup;
var mouseDown = false;
var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;
var rotationSpeed = 0.01;

// Perlin Noise

// var PerlinNoise = function() {  // <-- original code
function PerlinNoise() {           // <-- modified for snippet

  this.permutation = [
    151, 160, 137, 91, 90, 15, 131, 13, 201, 95, 96, 53, 194, 233, 7, 225,
    140, 36, 103, 30, 69, 142, 8, 99, 37, 240, 21, 10, 23, 190, 6, 148,
    247, 120, 234, 75, 0, 26, 197, 62, 94, 252, 219, 203, 117, 35, 11, 32,
    57, 177, 33, 88, 237, 149, 56, 87, 174, 20, 125, 136, 171, 168, 68, 175,
    74, 165, 71, 134, 139, 48, 27, 166, 77, 146, 158, 231, 83, 111, 229, 122,
    60, 211, 133, 230, 220, 105, 92, 41, 55, 46, 245, 40, 244, 102, 143, 54,
    65, 25, 63, 161, 1, 216, 80, 73, 209, 76, 132, 187, 208, 89, 18, 169,
    200, 196, 135, 130, 116, 188, 159, 86, 164, 100, 109, 198, 173, 186, 3,
    64, 52, 217, 226, 250, 124, 123, 5, 202, 38, 147, 118, 126, 255, 82, 85,
    212, 207, 206, 59, 227, 47, 16, 58, 17, 182, 189, 28, 42, 223, 183, 170,
    213, 119, 248, 152, 2, 44, 154, 163, 70, 221, 153, 101, 155, 167, 43, 172,
    9, 129, 22, 39, 253, 19, 98, 108, 110, 79, 113, 224, 232, 178, 185, 112,
    104, 218, 246, 97, 228, 251, 34, 242, 193, 238, 210, 144, 12, 191, 179,
    162, 241, 81, 51, 145, 235, 249, 14, 239, 107, 49, 192, 214, 31, 181, 199,
    106, 157, 184, 84, 204, 176, 115, 121, 50, 45, 127, 4, 150, 254, 138, 236,
    205, 93, 222, 114, 67, 29, 24, 72, 243, 141, 128, 195, 78, 66, 215, 61,
    156, 180
  ];
  this.p = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    this.p[256 + i] = this.p[i] = this.permutation[i];
  }
};

PerlinNoise.prototype.dot = function(g, x, y) {
  return g[0] * x + g[1] * y;
};

PerlinNoise.prototype.fade = function(t) {
  return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
};

PerlinNoise.prototype.lerp = function(t, a, b) {
  return a + t * (b - a);
};

PerlinNoise.prototype.grad = function(hash, x, y) {
  var h = hash & 7;
  var grad = [
    [1, 1],
    [-1, 1],
    [1, -1],
    [-1, -1],
    [1, 0],
    [-1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, -1]
  ];
  return this.dot(grad[h], x, y);
};

PerlinNoise.prototype.noise = function(x, y) {
  var X = Math.floor(x) & 255;
  var Y = Math.floor(y) & 255;
  x -= Math.floor(x);
  y -= Math.floor(y);
  var fadeX = this.fade(x);
  var fadeY = this.fade(y);

  var A = this.p[X] + Y;
  var B = this.p[X + 1] + Y;

  var AA = this.p[A];
  var AB = this.p[A + 1];
  var BA = this.p[B];
  var BB = this.p[B + 1];

  var u = this.lerp(fadeX, this.grad(AA, x, y), this.grad(BA, x - 1, y));
  var v = this.lerp(fadeX, this.grad(AB, x, y - 1), this.grad(BB, x - 1, y - 1));

  return (this.lerp(fadeY, u, v) + 1) / 2;
};

PerlinNoise.prototype.generateNoise = function(width, height, scale) {
  var noiseData = [];
  var maxNoiseHeight = -Infinity;
  var minNoiseHeight = Infinity;

  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    noiseData[y] = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var noise = this.noise(x / scale, y / scale);
      noiseData[y][x] = noise;
      if (noise > maxNoiseHeight) {
        maxNoiseHeight = noise;
      }
      if (noise < minNoiseHeight) {
        minNoiseHeight = noise;
      }
    }
  }

  // Normalize the noise values to range between 0 and 1
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      noiseData[y][x] = (noiseData[y][x] - minNoiseHeight) / (maxNoiseHeight - minNoiseHeight);
    }
  }

  return noiseData;
};

// Inicializar escena
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.getElementById("canvas-container").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Crear nuevos renderizadores para las vistas adicionales
  renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
  document.getElementById("canvas-container").appendChild(renderer2.domElement);

  renderer3 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer3.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
  document.getElementById("canvas-container").appendChild(renderer3.domElement);

  renderer4 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer4.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
  document.getElementById("canvas-container").appendChild(renderer4.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
}


// Función para manejar el evento de click izquierdo del mouse
function onMouseDown(event) {
  if (event.button === 0) {
    mouseDown = true;
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
  }
}

// Función para manejar el evento de soltar el click izquierdo del mouse
function onMouseUp(event) {
  if (event.button === 0) {
    mouseDown = false;
  }
}

// Función para manejar el evento de movimiento del mouse
function onMouseMove(event) {
  if (mouseDown) {
    var deltaX = event.clientX - mouseX;
    var deltaY = event.clientY - mouseY;
    llanuraGroup.rotation.y += deltaX * rotationSpeed;
    llanuraGroup.rotation.x += deltaY * rotationSpeed;
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
  }
}


function generarLlanura() {
  // Obtener preferencias de montaña del usuario
  var mountainInput = document.getElementById("mountainInput").value;
  var preferences = parseMountainPreferences(mountainInput);

  // Limpiar escena
  while (scene.children.length > 0) {
    scene.remove(scene.children[0]);
  }

  // Dividir la llanura en secciones
  var seccionesX = Math.random() * 10; // Número de secciones horizontales
  var seccionesZ = 5; // Número de secciones verticales

  // Generar geometría de la llanura
  var llanuraGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, seccionesX, seccionesZ);
  llanuraGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

  // Material de malla con color basado en la altura
  var colorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
  });

  // Crear grupo para la llanura
  llanuraGroup = new THREE.Group();

  // Generar montañas en cada sección de la llanura
  for (var i = 0; i <= seccionesX; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= seccionesZ; j++) {
      var seccionGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 10, 10);
      seccionGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
      seccionGeometry.translate((i - seccionesX / 2) * 20, 0, (j - seccionesZ / 2) * 20);

      // Deformar vértices de forma aleatoria utilizando Perlin Noise
      var vertices = seccionGeometry.attributes.position.array;
      var colors = [];

      for (var k = 0; k < vertices.length; k += 3) {
        var x = vertices[k];
        var y = vertices[k + 1];
        var z = vertices[k + 2];


        var altura = perlin.noise(x / 10, z / 10) * 10; // Ajusta el rango de altura de las montañas aquí


        // Aplicar preferencias de montaña
        if (preferences.size === "pequeñas") {
          altura *= 0.5;
        } else if (preferences.size === "grandes") {
          altura *= 1.5;
        }

        // Calcular color basado en la altura (gradiente de color con rojo oscuro)
        var color = new THREE.Color(0x00FF00); // Color predeterminado (verde)
        var darkColor = new THREE.Color(0xFF0000); // Color oscuro (rojo oscuro)

        var t = (altura + 5) / 10; // Escala de 0 a 1
        color.lerpHSL(darkColor, t); // Interpolación lineal entre verde y rojo oscuro

        vertices[k + 1] = altura;
        colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
      }

      // Aplicar colores a la geometría
      seccionGeometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

      // Crear malla de la sección
      var seccionMesh = new THREE.Mesh(seccionGeometry, colorMaterial);
      llanuraGroup.add(seccionMesh);
    }
  }

  // Añadir el grupo a la escena
  scene.add(llanuraGroup);
}

// Función para analizar las preferencias de montaña del usuario
function parseMountainPreferences(input) {
  var preferences = {
    size: "normales" // Valor predeterminado
  };

  // Analizar preferencias
  var words = input.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  if (words.includes("pequeñas")) {
    preferences.size = "pequeñas";
  } else if (words.includes("grandes")) {
    preferences.size = "grandes";
  }

  return preferences;
}


// Renderizar
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  // Renderizar la vista principal
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // Renderizar vistas adicionales
  renderer2.render(scene, llanuraGroup.userData.camera);
  renderer3.render(scene, llanuraGroup2.userData.camera);
  renderer4.render(scene, llanuraGroup3.userData.camera);
}


// Configurar cámara
function setupCamera() {
  var llanuraBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(llanuraGroup);
  var llanuraSize = llanuraBoundingBox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
  var llanuraCenter = llanuraBoundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

  var distance = Math.max(llanuraSize.x, llanuraSize.y, llanuraSize.z) * 1.5;
  var cameraPosition = llanuraCenter.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0, distance, distance));

  camera.position.copy(cameraPosition);
  camera.lookAt(llanuraCenter);

  // Ajustar la cámara para las vistas laterales
  setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup, 50);
}

// Inicializar y renderizar
function setup() {
  init();
  generarLlanura();
  generarOtrasLlanuras();
  setupCamera();
  render();


}

function generarOtrasLlanuras() {
  // Crear nuevas llanuras
  llanuraGroup2 = llanuraGroup.clone();
  llanuraGroup3 = llanuraGroup.clone();

  // Mover las nuevas llanuras a posiciones diferentes
  llanuraGroup.position.set(0, 0, -50);
  llanuraGroup2.position.set(0, 0, -100);
  llanuraGroup3.position.set(0, 0, -150);

  // Añadir las nuevas llanuras a la escena
  scene.add(llanuraGroup2);
  scene.add(llanuraGroup3);

  // Ajustar cámaras y posiciones para las vistas laterales
  setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup, 50);
  setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup2, -50);
  setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup3, -100);
}

// Configurar cámara para vistas laterales
function setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup, distance) {
  if (!llanuraGroup.userData) {
    llanuraGroup.userData = {};
  }

  var llanuraBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(llanuraGroup);
  var llanuraSize = llanuraBoundingBox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
  var llanuraCenter = llanuraBoundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

  var cameraPosition = llanuraCenter.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0, llanuraSize.y * 0.5, distance));

  // Configurar cámara para mirar al centro de la llanuraGroup
  llanuraGroup.userData.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  llanuraGroup.userData.camera.position.copy(cameraPosition);
  llanuraGroup.userData.camera.lookAt(llanuraCenter);
}
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var newWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var newHeight = window.innerHeight;

  // Ajustar el tamaño del canvas principal
  renderer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
  camera.aspect = newWidth / newHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // Ajustar el tamaño de los canvas de las vistas adicionales
  var halfWidth = newWidth / 2;
  var halfHeight = newHeight / 2;

  renderer2.setSize(halfWidth, halfHeight);
  renderer3.setSize(halfWidth, halfHeight);
  renderer4.setSize(halfWidth, halfHeight);

  // Ajustar el tamaño de las cámaras de las vistas adicionales
  setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup, 50);
  setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup2, -50);
  setupCameraForView(llanuraGroup3, -100);
});


// Llamar a la función de configuración al cargar la página
window.onload = setup;


// Code block II

// Configuración de la API de reconocimiento de voz
const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.interimResults = true;

const voiceButton = document.getElementById("voiceButton");
const voiceOutput = document.getElementById("voiceOutput");

voiceButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  recognition.start();
});

recognition.onresult = (event) => {
  const result = event.results[event.results.length - 1];
  const transcript = result[0].transcript;
  voiceOutput.innerHTML = `Has dicho: ${transcript}`;
  processVoiceCommand(transcript);
};

recognition.onend = () => {
  recognition.start();
};

function processVoiceCommand(transcript) {
  if (transcript.includes("generar llanura")) {
    generarLlanura();
  } else if (transcript.includes("generar montañas pequeñas")) {
    const input = document.getElementById("mountainInput");
    input.value = "pequeñas";
    generarLlanura();
  } else if (transcript.includes("generar montañas grandes")) {
    const input = document.getElementById("mountainInput");
    input.value = "grandes";
    generarLlanura();
  }
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#canvas-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#canvas-container-small {
  width: 48%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#canvas2,
#canvas3,
#canvas4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#voiceButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}


/* for Stack Overflow snippet only */

.as-console {
  color: black !important;
}
<input type="text" id="mountainInput" placeholder="Preferencias de Montañas (pequeñas o grandes)">
<button onclick="generarLlanura()">Generar Llanura</button>

<div id="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas3" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas4" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
</div>

<button id="voiceButton">Iniciar Reconocimiento de Voz</button>
<div id="voiceOutput"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
Return to post
```